# How to get Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168 work on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, hp, intel-wireless

I searched many solutions on this site but most of them were referring to Broadcom Wifi drivers while mine has Intel one.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
arijit@HP-AU134TX:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
DeviceName: Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3168 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
```

Output of `rfkill list`

```
arijit@HP-AU134TX:~$ rfkill list

arijit@HP-AU134TX:~$
```

**i.e No Output**

Output of `uname -a; dmesg | grep iwl`

```
arijit@HP-AU134TX:~$ uname -a; dmesg | grep iwl

Linux HP-AU134TX 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `uname -a; dmesg | grep iwl` terminal command.

Answer (score 12):

Connect to the internet by some other way and install the 4.8+ kernel

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

You also need firmware for this device. Update your system by

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

and the firmware will be installed.

Reboot and the wireless device should work.

To get it working out of the box, you need to install Ubuntu 16.04.2+ that has support of this device.

Comment: YES! Fantastic. Three hours of trying until I came across this!

Comment: If someone is looking for another solution, here it is! It works! [Unofficial Driver](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Realtek-8723DE-wifi-module-Linux-driver-available-now-Ubuntu/m-p/6477307#M146067)

Comment: you need load previous kernel. on 4.35