# Acer Aspire ES1-572 not recognizing wifi chipset?

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

I'm unable to connect to my wifi network after clean installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Machine is new and was running Windows 10 with no wifi issues prior to install.  I'm very new to Linux but have been attempting to apply other fixes to this issues as I stumble across other questions, so far to no avail.  I have a feeling its a driver issue, but I can't find the correct solution to apply. Any help is much appreciated!

lspci brings up:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller (rev 21)
00:1e.4 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d2b (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fb (rev 10)
```

results for -a; lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list

```
Linux Treesnail-Workstation 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3168 work on Ubuntu 16.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/868075/how-to-get-intel-dual-bandwireless-ac-3168-work-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the 4.8 kernel and firmware. Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
```

Reboot.

Comment: I finally found the previous answer.

Comment: Still not seeing any wifi options in the networking settings.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Did the packages install OK? Please add output of `uname -a; lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` to your question.

Comment: everything seemed to install correctly.  answer updated.

Comment: The kernel did not install. Did you reboot?

Comment: I did.  Shall I try to run the command again and reboot?

Comment: Run the command and post the output.

Comment: Nope, my fault.  I guess the command did not run the first time.  Everything looks great now!!  Thank you Pilot!!!

Comment: If @Pilot6 's answer was helpful, please accept it: http://askubuntu.com/tour